# Large volume of queries on a large CSV file

Tags: mongodb, csv, unix, awk

I am trying to query a large csv file(100gb,+-1.1billion records) for partial matches in the url column of a csv. I aim to query for about 23000 possible matches.

Example input:

```
url,answer,rrClass,rrType,tlp,firstSeenTimestamp,lastSeenTimestamp,minimumTTLSec,maximumTTLSec,count
maps.google.com.,173.194.112.106,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
drive.google.com.,173.194.112.107,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
nokiantires.com.,185.53.179.22,in,a,white,1529534626596,1529534626596,600,600,1
woodpapersilk.,138.201.32.142,in,a,white,1546339972354,1553285334535,3886,14399,2
xn--c1yn36f.cn.,167.160.174.76,in,a,white,1501685257255,1515592226520,14400,14400,38
maps.google.com.malwaredomain.com.,118.193.165.236,in,a,white,1442148766000,1442148766000,600,600,1
whois.ducmates.blogspot.com.,216.58.194.193,in,a,white,1535969280784,1535969280784,44,44,1
```

Queries are of the following pattern: `/^.*[someurl].*$/` each of these [someurls] come from a different file and can be assumed as an array of size 23000.

Matching Queries:

`awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*google\.com\.$/' > file1.out
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*nokiantires\.com\.$/' > file2.out
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*woodpapersilk\.com\.$/' > file3.out
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*xn--.*$/' > file4.out`

Queries that match nothing:

`awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*seasonvintage\.com\.$/' > file5.out
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*java2s\.com\.$/' > file6.out`

file1.out:

```
maps.google.com.,173.194.112.106,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
drive.google.com.,173.194.112.107,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
```

file2.out:

```
nokiantires.com.,185.53.179.22,in,a,white,1529534626596,1529534626596,600,600,1
```

file3.out:

```
woodpapersilk.,138.201.32.142,in,a,white,1546339972354,1553285334535,3886,14399,2
```

file4.out:

```
xn--c1yn36f.cn.,167.160.174.76,in,a,white,1501685257255,1515592226520,14400,14400,38
```

file 5.out and file6.out are both empty as nothing matches
I have also uploaded these inputs and outputs as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Ralphhorn/c4dadbe313d8309b4400ff1a043ebd85).

Essentially each query extracts a partial match in the url column.

Currently I use the following code with awk to search for possible matches:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^.*xn--.*$/' file.out > filter.csv
```

This solution returns a valid response but it takes 14 minutes to query for one example. Unfortunately I am looking to query for 23000 possible matches.

As such I am looking for a more workable and efficient solution.

I have thought of/tried the following

1. Can i include all the tags in a huge regex or does this increase the inefficiency?
2. I have tried using MongoDB but it does not work well with just a single machine.
3. I have an AWS voucher that has about $30 left. Is there any particular AWS solution that could help here?

What would be a more workable solution to process these queries on said csv file?

Many thanks

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include, say, 10 lines of sample input along with, say, 4 or 5 "queries" you want to match (2 or 3 that do and a 1 or 2 that don't match) and the expected output from that then we can probably help you. What is `pv`? How does it being present or not affect the execution time of your script?

Comment: I see you've now provided 2 "Example" records along with 4 queries that best I can tell won't match any of them, and no expected output. There may be a very efficient answer to your question but without more truly representative sample input/output we'd just be guessing. So please re-read my comment and provide what I suggested so we can help you. Provide the input/output as a block of text (use the editors `{}` button), not a numbered list, so we can copy/paste it to test with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, burning the midnight oil is not helping my explanation of the problem at all. I will catch some sleep and rephrase in the morning with some proper Input/Output.

Thanks for helping out, asking a question on Stack Overflow is much harder than expected.

Comment: It can be easy to ask a question but then YMMV with the answers you get. The more effort you put into asking a good question the better chance you'll get a good answer. All it takes to ask a good question is concise, testable sample input that's truly representative of your real data, the expected output given that input. the code you've tried so far, what's wrong with the output it's producing, a clear statement of your requirements, and what exactly you need help with. You've got all the hard stuff already covered, all we need now is more truly representative input/output. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated the original question with hopefully, some proper input and output. I also included an edge case that should not match. Thanks for spotting the regex escape error. I have also removed the star from the end of the regex as the pattern should only match to the end of the string. 

Is this input/output helpful for answering the question?
PS: I provided a link to a gist that contains all the input and output as files.

Comment: Yes, much better. I just tidied up the info to provide one concrete sample input file. Now - can a query match multiple lines? If one query matches a line can a second query also match the same line? I've no idea what gist is but I won't be clicking on external links anyway.

Comment: You don't really expect `woodpapersilk.com` from the queries to match against `woodpapersilk.` (no `.com`) in the input file, right?

Comment: That is correct. Essentially I am trying to match the last part(root) of a domain. so anything in front of `woodpapersilk.com` should match. `woodpapersilk.` should not match as it misses the top level domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what we know so far and guessing at the answers to a couple of questions, I'd approach this by separating the queries into "queries that can be matched by a hash lookup" (which is all but 1 of the queries in your posted example) and "queries that need a regexp comparison to match" (just `xn--.*$` in your example) and then evaluating them as such when reading your records so that any $1 that can be matched by an almost instantaneous hash lookup against all hash-able queries will be done like that and only the few that need a regexp match will be handled sequentially in a loop:

```
$ cat ../queries
google.com.$
nokiantires.com.$
woodpapersilk.com.$
xn--.*$
seasonvintage.com.$
java2s.com.$

$ cat ../records
url,answer,rrClass,rrType,tlp,firstSeenTimestamp,lastSeenTimestamp,minimumTTLSec,maximumTTLSec,count
maps.google.com.,173.194.112.106,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
drive.google.com.,173.194.112.107,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
nokiantires.com.,185.53.179.22,in,a,white,1529534626596,1529534626596,600,600,1
woodpapersilk.,138.201.32.142,in,a,white,1546339972354,1553285334535,3886,14399,2
xn--c1yn36f.cn.,167.160.174.76,in,a,white,1501685257255,1515592226520,14400,14400,38
maps.google.com.malwaredomain.com.,118.193.165.236,in,a,white,1442148766000,1442148766000,600,600,1
whois.ducmates.blogspot.com.,216.58.194.193,in,a,white,1535969280784,1535969280784,44,44,1
```

.

```
$ cat ../tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==FNR {
    query = $0
    outFile = "file" ++numQueries ".out"
    printf "" > outFile; close(outFile)
    if ( query ~ /^[^.]+[.][^.]+[.][$]$/ ) {
        # simple end of field string, can be hash matched
        queriesHash[query] = outFile
    }
    else {
        # not a simple end of field string, must be regexp matched
        queriesRes[query] = outFile
    }
    next
}
FNR>1 {
    matchQuery = ""
    if ( match($1,/[^.]+[.][^.]+[.]$/) ) {
        fldKey = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH) "$"
        if ( fldKey in queriesHash ) {
            matchType  = "hash"
            matchQuery = fldKey
            outFile    = queriesHash[matchQuery]
        }
    }
    if ( matchQuery == "" ) {
        for ( query in queriesRes ) {
            if ( $1 ~ query ) {
                matchType  = "regexp"
                matchQuery = query
                outFile    = queriesRes[matchQuery]
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if ( matchQuery != "" ) {
        print "matched:", matchType, matchQuery, $0, ">>", outFile | "cat>&2"
        print >> outFile; close(outFile)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ ls
$
$ tail -n +1 *
tail: cannot open '*' for reading: No such file or directory
```

.

```
$ awk -f ../tst.awk ../queries ../records
matched: hash google.com.$ maps.google.com.,173.194.112.106,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2 >> file1.out
matched: hash google.com.$ drive.google.com.,173.194.112.107,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2 >> file1.out
matched: hash nokiantires.com.$ nokiantires.com.,185.53.179.22,in,a,white,1529534626596,1529534626596,600,600,1 >> file2.out
matched: regexp xn--.*$ xn--c1yn36f.cn.,167.160.174.76,in,a,white,1501685257255,1515592226520,14400,14400,38 >> file4.out
```

.

```
$ ls
file1.out  file2.out  file3.out  file4.out  file5.out  file6.out
$
$ tail -n +1 *
==> file1.out <==
maps.google.com.,173.194.112.106,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2
drive.google.com.,173.194.112.107,in,a,white,1442011301000,1442011334000,300,300,2

==> file2.out <==
nokiantires.com.,185.53.179.22,in,a,white,1529534626596,1529534626596,600,600,1

==> file3.out <==

==> file4.out <==
xn--c1yn36f.cn.,167.160.174.76,in,a,white,1501685257255,1515592226520,14400,14400,38

==> file5.out <==

==> file6.out <==
$
```

The initial `printf "" > outFile; close(outFile)` is just to ensure you get an output file per query even if that query oesn't match, just like you asked for in your example.

If you're using GNU awk then it can manage the multiple open output files for you and then you can make these changes:

1. `printf "" > outFile; close(outFile)` -> `printf "" > outFile`
2. `print >> outFile; close(outFile)` -> `print > outFile`

which will be more efficient because then the output file isn't being opened+closed on every print.

Comment: Oke, this is interesting. How does this perform when performing 10 queries vs 1000 queries? Also I tried executing the code on my machine but i can not seem to get it working. Awk gives a syntax error:
`awk: cmd. line:5:             if (index($1,query) {
awk: cmd. line:5:                                 ^ syntax error
`
What should exactly be contained in the queries file? Currently I have the following file: google.com amazon.com About string comparisons, is it correct to assume that it would not work in this case as I am trying to specifically match the end of the string?

Comment: It was missing a closing `)` on the line, fixed now. It'll be slower for 1000 queries than 10 since it's looping on the number of queries. That may not be [entirely] necessary (see my updated answer). A string comparison would work but if it's got to be at the end of the string then you'd need to add a numeric comparison on the length too, e.g. `(index($1,query) + length(query)) == length($1)`. I've updated my answer based on the sample input/output you provided.

Comment: I am going to dive into the answer and try to understand it properly. It is a bit out of my wheelhouse as I am very new to awk and bash. However, this is the kind of solution I was looking for in terms of scalability. One last question if possible, is it correct to assume that the performance scales linearly with the number of queries in this implementation?


Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. The performance will hardly change at all whether you have 10 or 1000 **hashable** queries as those just require a hash lookup to match but it will scale linearly with the number of non-hashable (i.e. requiring a regexp) queries as those require a loop to match. Feel free to ask questions as you poke at it.

Comment: thanks, I notice that the code is very fast if there are not many records found. However, once the number of matching records increases, it can become significantly slower. Is there a way to optimize the writing speed or is this a problem related to nvme disks?

Is there also a way to let's say only write the first 10 records found to optimize this further?

The GNU version is awesome, it makes a significant difference.

Comment: If a separate output file per matching query wasn't required then the script would run faster since it wouldn't need to keep opening/closing new output files with each write. The GNU version will keep some number of output files open simultaneously for you but will still be opening/closing as more matches are found. Apart from that idk if anything else would make a noticable difference. To quit after `n` matches just add `if (++cnt == n) exit` after the `print` line and call the script as `awk -v n=10 -f tst.awk ...`